# Efficiency of light collection of a lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, photon-emission, camera, medical-physics

I am trying to calculate the theoretical imaging performance of a scintillator & camera combination, (scintillator is a plane that emits optical light under X-ray exposure).

My question is I found some equations that express the light-collection efficiency based on geometric optics for a point source or Lambertian surface, but I am a little confused. The efficiency(%) of a camera-point source is given by $$Efficiency = \frac{T}{16n^2(F\#)^2(1+M)^2}$$, where T is the transmission of the lens, n is the refractive index of the point scintillator, F# is the f-number of lens, and M is the magnification of the imaging system, where M=object/Image. The equation for an extended Lambertian source is $$Efficiency = \frac{T}{1+4(F\#)^2(1+M)^2}$$

source-paper: Methods to calculate the lens efficiency in optically coupled CCD x-ray imaging systems

My question is what is this efficiency over area wise? For example, many groups use the extended Lambertian surface equation to estimate photon-capture, but my question is this equation doesn't factor in pixel size. If I have a scintillator plane that emits 2200 photons on the optical axis and my camera parameters state an efficiency of 0.20, how does the detection of the '462' photons come in, when I can have a camera with 6.45um pixel or 50um pixels? I'm just trying to estimate photons per pixels to some degree given a 2D light-source that at each point will emit X photons.

Thanks

Comment: my guess is the first formula is for the entire system, i.e if the scintillator releases 1M photons and eff is 50% then 0.5M photons hit the ccd ... as long as the CCD is large enough to capture entire image.  Then the pixel math just depends on 0.5M / # pixels.